# AWS S3 Object deletion, Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following situation, I'm storing images in S3, each image is inside its own folder, something like this:

```
https://s3.eu-central-9.amazonaws.com/my-app/6a68045c14754f3c0b22d206053ff67406217981043a24ad06d3789b67024747125b8900ee8a1e9af2220a5c6558946136cd82807d0666b4678406337239530f/1535565432.jpg
```

I'm using AWS SDK, I've tried two approaches:

- Passing the full path
- Passing only the path after my-app

With both I get a response looking like this:

```
{ Deleted: [ { Key: '/1b37c7ad1d9f021e000813b9d16b8ae2b24e6ed6f3c4430bfb8196ca63eec57eafe5bf2ee8993a7846faca0c95cec587395d6639f2aeb73447fb9429b673f0ca/1535564545.jpg' } ],
Errors: [] }
```

But if I go and check my bucket, the file and the folder are both in place, can't figure out why, any suggestions?

I'm starting to think I just should skip the folder creation and add the images in the root of the bucket.

**[UPDATE]** 
Params for S3.deleteObjects method:

```
{ 
    Bucket: 'my-app',
    Delete: { 
        Objects: [{
            Key: '/c506c3b842e1729c41542b7867b14a5eefb4159336105392ed99d250153aeea515e39986f850e3c8674d082b760b7e0d3ab5edf1c7c3e5d89ea7e71a399c0e5e/1535610612.jpg' 
        }] 
    } 
}
```

I am using the serverless framework, the bucket is created with the help of it - could that have something to do with this? The only error I got while building this is that my lambda function which is doing the delete did not have permission to do it, once I added s3:DeleteObject I got greeted with this.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using? Everything looks fine. Do you have versioning enabled on your bucket?

Comment: @Cheruvian Versioning is disabled. Which part of the code exactly?

Comment: SDKs typically expect you to provide the bucket name (my-app) and the object key (6a68...530f/1535565432.jpg).

Comment: @jarmod Yup, updated the question with the params I pass in.

Comment: The object key doesn't start with a / and the bucket name is my-app and in your Objects array you actually need objects, each with a Key property. Please read the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

Comment: @jarmod Updated question, I oversimplified my sample code, sorry. I'm using typescript so it wouldn't have compiles if I'd be missing the Key property, and I think I would get an error from the sdk as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in the way you are indicating the S3 bucket and key to the SDK. They are currently being supplied as follows:

```
Bucket: https://s3.eu-central-9.amazonaws.com/my-app
Key: /1234.jpg
```

They should be supplied as follows:

```
Bucket: my-app
Key: 1234.jpg
```

If the object is in a subfolder structure, then it would be:

```
Bucket: my-app
Key: folder1/folder2/1234.jpg
```

Part of the problem here, I think, is that you were providing the information incorrectly but S3 was responding with OK. If you ask S3 to delete an object that does not exist, it will return OK. It's a security thing.